# Display Current date in datepicker dialog in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I tried so many times to show current date in my date-picker dialog but failed .
It shows 1/1/1990 .
i already follow some answer from stack overflow but these are not working for me unfortunately.
can anyone please explain me the code for display current date in datepicker dialog. 
Thanks.

Comment: you can set mindate in date picker as current date

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  //It may help you. 

public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        Calendar calendar;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));


            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            today = calendar.getTime();

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            System.out.print("Current_time::::"+calendar.getTime());
            populateSetDate(yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {

            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            pick = calendar.getTime();


                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String formattedDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());

                txtview.setText(formattedDate);





        }

    }
```

Comment: thats helpful . can i write same thing without extend Dialogfragment or implementing . why i have to use DialogFragment actually ?

Comment: yes you can use it without extending or implementing. if it is helpful to you then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 new Date().getDate();
```

But since it's deprecated, use this,

```
    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePick);
    datePicker.setMinDate(c.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private DatePicker datePicker;
   private Calendar calendar;
   private TextView dateView;
   private int year, month, day;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
      calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

      month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      showDate(year, month+1, day);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public void setDate(View view) {
      showDialog(999);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ca", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   }

   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if (id == 999) {
         return new DatePickerDialog(this, 
            myDateListener, year, month, day);
      }
      return null;
   }

   private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new 
      DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, 
         int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // arg1 = year
         // arg2 = month
         // arg3 = day
         showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
      }
   };

   private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
      dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
      .append(month).append("/").append(year));
   }
}
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/